# Can't Uninstall ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net

With AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe out,  I want to have a clean install.
I tried uninstall of DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi but it erred
Anyone knows how to get rid of the older version? I have beta 8 installed

Answer (score -2):

Go to the root folder of v5.0 framework, similar to the following via command prompt.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

and execute the following :

> aspnet_regiis -e -u

Comment: That's why I mentioned "similar". I don't know how the folder structure looks like for 5

Comment: Please don't guess at answers when you could be telling people  actions which do more harm than good. .Net 5 is a massive shift from 4 and does not install a framework folder similar to the path above. I also haven't run it but I very much doubt the aspnet_regiis command you state would have any affect on ASP.Net 5 since it doesn't run thought IIS in the same way as previous versions.